# Bundler, Rails3: how to avoid git check of edge gems in :test group during deploying?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I have such lines in Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  ...
  gem 'cucumber', :git => "git://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber.git"
  ...
end
```

When I try do deploy on server via `bundle install --deployment --quiet --without development test`, I get an error:

```
 sh: git: command not found
 ** An error has occurred in git when running `git clone "git://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber.git" "/home/test/rails_apps/test_app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/cache/bundler/git/cucumber-3eb3f1a09813a1271fada66aac31d953ef2ad625" --bare --no-hardlinks. Cannot complete bundling.
```

I have no git executable on server. But I don't want to use git because cucumber in :test group, and I execute bundler with "--without test"!

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no way to do this. Because this is feature of bundler

> Note that on bundle install, bundler
>   downloads and evaluates all gems, in
>   order to create a single canonical
>   list of all of the required gems and
>   their dependencies. This means that
>   you cannot list different versions of
>   the same gems in different groups. For
>   more details, see Understanding
>   Bundler.

http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html (see GROUPS part)

What about you haven't git or any gems at your server. You should use `bundle pack`. But, now `bundle pack` [don't work with git](http://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/labels/git#issue/67). Then you should pack git sources manually:

```
cd vendor/git
git clone git://github.com/foo/foo.git
```

Then, in your Gemfile,

> gem "foo", :path => "vendor/git/foo"

.

http://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/labels/git#issue/67